# Is it possible to 'require' a object in Node.js that can access the importing files global scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots

I've done a fair bit of searching around to see if this is possible. So far, from what I understand, it isn't.

In my `main.js` file, I have this code:

```
var commands = require('./commands.js');
```

It imports an object from `commands.js`, that is set out in the following manner:

```
module.exports = {
   var1: "something" + somevar,
   var2: "something" + someothervar,
   ...
}
```

This allows me to access the object `commands` from within the `main.js` file as though it was just declaed within `main.js` itself. However, I run into a problem when I want the exporting `commands.js` file to be able to access `main.js`'s global variable scope. Say that `somevar` and `someothervar` are part of `main.js`'s global scope, when I want to get a value from `commands` I don't want them to be 'undefined'.

Long story short, I want to treat this imported object *exactly* as though it was just declared in `main.js`.

I'm trying to code a chatbot for Discord, and for the sake of tidyness and organization, I wanted to have the list of functions it can use separate from the code that processes them. Is this worth the effort? Is there a better way to do this? I'm also juggling around SQL at the moment, trying to design the most modular/customizable program possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible , when you export a module all the variables would have been resolved .

You will always get the object with all the expressions evaluated when you import

I would suggest make var1 and var2 as functions

```
module.exports = {
   var1: function(someVar){ return "something" + someVar},
   var2: function(someothervar) {return "something" + someothervar},
   ...
}

Now when you import it in main.js ,pass your somevar and someothervar
```

Comment: I expect I'd have to make the `module.exports` object elements all strings, and then use .eval() when processing them, perhaps.

Comment: you can use a different route

Comment: Your suggestion is a good idea, one that I actually was considering looking at earlier but forgot about for some reason. Thanks for the answer.